# git command from mac terminal to point to branch instead of master

Tags: git

I am trying to push changes from local file to git . I am using mac terminal git commands . Currently "git status" command shows below

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
```

How do I change git to point to a branch which is created under this master ?

Comment: What do you mean with `push changes from local file to git`? If you modify a file, and it's already tracked by git, git will tell you that it has changed and then you can add it to index and commit it.... pushing is related to the operation of putting a revision (working tree and history) on a remote repository.

Comment: It's really not clear what you're trying to do. If you can update your question to make it more clear we might be able to help out.

Comment: Currently when I do git status , see above , it is pointing to origin/master ...How do I change to a branch under the master

Comment: my question I should have asked - How do I point the head to a branch other than Master .. I think I got the answer - I should use  git checkout <branch name>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Currently when I do git status , see above , it is pointing to origin/master ..

No: it points to master.
Only a [`git checkout <branch>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) would change that to another (existing) branch.

See the list of your current branches with [`git branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch)

See more with [`learngitbranching.js.org`](https://learngitbranching.js.org/)